# Symfony: How to join tables?

Tags: php, sql, join, symfony1, doctrine

I am working on exiting project. I want to join two tables in SQL query.

```
$this->chapterPages = Doctrine_Query::create()
                     ->from( 'Page' )
                     ->leftJoin('PageAnchor pa ON pa.page_id = Page.sortorder')
                     ->where( 'Page.chapter_id = ?', $this->chapterId )
                     ->execute();

$this->chapterPages = $this->chapterPages->toArray();
```

But I am getting following error:

> "PageAnchor" with an alias of "pa" in your query does not reference
>   the parent component it is related to., referer: example.com/abc/abc

Any idea ?

Comment: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/69063/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->chapterPages = Doctrine_Query::create()
                 ->from( 'Page p' )
                 ->leftJoin('p.PageAnchor pa ON pa.page_id = Page.sortorder')
                 ->where( 'Page.chapter_id = ?', $this->chapterId )
                 ->execute();
```

Reference:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/dql-doctrine-query-language:join-syntax